# I get System.ObjectDisposedException, cant seem to find whats wrong

Tags: c#

At the first add method i get the exception:
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

I know i need to be in the using() brackets and it is, and Transaction is public  virtual

```
  public void confirmPayments(List<int> Payments)
    {
        using (var db = new BankContext())
        {
        try
        {
                foreach (int a in Payments)
                {
                    foreach (Payment payment in db.Payment)
                    {
                        if (a == payment.Id)
                        {
                            Transaction senderTransaction = new Transaction
                            {
                                Amount = payment.Amount,
                                CreationDate = payment.CreationDate,
                                DueDate = payment.DueDate,
                                Receiver = payment.Receiver,
                                Sender = payment.Sender,
                                KIDMessage = payment.KIDMessage
                            };
                            Transaction receiverTranscation = new Transaction
                            {
                                Amount = payment.Amount,
                                CreationDate = payment.CreationDate,
                                DueDate = payment.DueDate,
                                Receiver = payment.Receiver,
                                Sender = payment.Sender,
                                KIDMessage = payment.KIDMessage
                            };

                            Account senderAccount = findAccount(senderTransaction.Sender);
                            Account receiverAccount = findAccount(receiverTranscation.Receiver);

                            senderAccount.Transaction.Add(senderTransaction);
                            senderAccount.Payment.Remove(payment);
                            senderAccount.Balance = senderAccount.Balance - senderTransaction.Amount;

                            receiverAccount.Transaction.Add(receiverTranscation);
                            receiverAccount.Balance = receiverAccount.Balance + receiverTranscation.Amount;
                        }
                    }
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FAILED TO CONFIRM PAYMENT: \n" + error.Message + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

The table/class that im trying to add into(codefirst):

```
    public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountType { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string ClosingDate { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Transaction> Transaction { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Payment> Payment { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Those functions that you are calling (findAccount in particular) look very suspicious; you should be able to attach the debugger and get the actual location where it throws.

Comment: What is `findAccount()`?  Is it fetching an object from a completely different DB context and disposing of that context?

Comment: @David Thanks!, this worked.. Did not think it would matter because findAccount() is using() same database...

Answer (score 0):

findAccount() is also using(var db = New BankContext()) which i think messes With the other using from the confirmPayments().